# Execute js code before committing "submit" in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

i can't seem to make the old js scripts that i found on the magical SO.

```
<div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, class:"btn btn-success create-campaign" %>

  </div>
```

this is my submit button.But there is a problem.

```
<div class="message-div" id="textField" contenteditable="true" maxlength="180"></div> 
<%= f.input :message ,as: :text,as: :hidden  ,input_html: { class: 'special', maxlength:'180' } %>
```

i use div to get the input for what i have done for it but my form takes its input from the hidden text area.

So i tried to do take take the content of the div and write it to the text area when submit button clicked.

but the js script that i wrote does not getting executed.

```
$(document).on("click",".create-campaign",function(e){

console.log('asdasd');

var a = $('.message-div').html();


document.getElementById('.special').value = a;

});
```

this is the code.

When i changed the listener class to another button, it works without a problem ( at least i see console log) but not when the submit button is pressed.

What should i do?

Cheers.

Comment: where is myTextarea class in input field?

Comment: @urjitonrails yeah sorry i copied it from ctrl-z guess i did too much.I'll edit the question but thats not the problem since the code doesn't even come to the console part.

Answer (score 2):

You need to prevent the default submit action from being triggered:

```
$(".create-campaign").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.info('asdasd');
  var a = $('.message-div').html();
  alert(a); // just to check that your data is there
  document.getElementById('.special').value = a;
  $("#YOUR_FORM_ID").submit();
});
```

Comment: just tried it, didn't work, it didnt prevent the submit.I called it in my view between js script tags

Comment: Are you wrapping your JS with 'jQuery(document).ready(function() {});' ? You should also move this into some asset file under 'app/assets/javascripts/' and not directly include this in your view.

Comment: It might be because you are calling getElementById with a class selected ".special" instead of calling getElementsByClassName("special")[0].value or $(".special").val()